# Enabling encryption in .NET sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption

I'm new to C# development.

In PHP we use

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
```

What is its equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SSLStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) appears to do what you want

```
var tcp = new TcpClient(machineName,443);
var ssl = new SslStream(tcp.GetStream);
```

You can specify a callback for doing certification validation. Otherwise it appears to default to the system's policy ( which I believe is what I.E. also uses by default)