# Encrypted packets over Sockets [C#]

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption, packet

I'm trying to do some sort Server which handles Client packets in C# (some sort of an Authentication Platform) and I need encryption for the packets. I've been searching on the Internet and I didn't find what I was searching.

I also thought about using RSA (4096) but I am not sure of this idea.

Can you recommend me a safe and good (strong too) to encrypt packets, please?

Regards.

Comment: HTTPS encrypts packets...

Comment: I know that HTTPS encrypts packets, but I'm using Sockets, not passing the data trough a Website...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373920/enabling-encryption-in-net-sockets?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx
SslStream. If not you have to build your own Mechanism.